# Full of hex codes in ILSpy, dNSpy, dotPeek

Tags: c#, decompiling, ilspy, dotpeek, dnspy

I'm trying to explore things with decompiling and I think I hit a wall because I think this is too much for a simple guy like me to comprehend. Is this normal? Or like the developer of the software (exe file) protected/secured it? Is there any workaround for this?

[image: Assemply Explorer File Names]

[image: Example File Content]

I have this as well though:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: Guid("0354977a-6aee-4ced-8222-83e581a05ec6")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1", FrameworkDisplayName = ".NET Framework 4.6.1")]
```

Comment: Its obfuscated code.

Comment: I see. So I'll be assuming it was intentionally left like that so it will be hard (almost unable) to reverse-engineer. Thanks, @tkausl!

Answer (score 0):

It`s obfuscated code., i.e. the compiled code goes through a tool to make class names, member variables, etc. as unreadable for humans as possible. That's done in order to increase the effort for reverse engineering and thus protect intellectual capital.

One of the first product IMHO was [dotfuscator](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/). In the meanwhile there are [plenty more](https://github.com/NotPrab/.NET-Obfuscator).